# jQuery dropdown menu hide ul li ul

Tags: jquery, css

I'm completely new to **jQuery**. I'm trying to understand why this drop down menu appears before the jQuery effect. I can't disable the `"ul li ul"` so it's only handled by **jQuery** .. I'd really appreciate any thoughts on this.

I've included the link to the site [here](http://www.vardverket.se)

As soon as you hover the menu the ul flies out and then the jQuery effect is executed ...

Here is the JavaScript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.menu-meny-1-container ul li').hoverIntent({
      over : navover,
      out : navout,
      timeout : 400
    });
    // (how to use both fade and slide effects!):
    function navover(){
      jQuery(this).children('ul')
        .stop(true,true)
        .fadeIn({duration:600,queue:false})
        .css('display','none')
        .slideDown(600);
    }
    function navout(){
      jQuery(this).children('ul')
        .stop(true,true)
        .fadeOut({duration:300,queue:false})
        .slideUp(300);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    border-left: 0 none;
    display: block;
}
.main-navigation li ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.main-navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you put the problem code up on [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

```
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    border-left: 0 none;
    display: none; /* CHANGED 'BLOCK' TO 'NONE' */
}
```